# iphone - Should I rely on NSManagedObjectId to exchange NSManagedObject between contexts?

Tags: iphone, performance, core-data, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

This is a `design question` and the following is the background of my problem.

---

### Problem

I am writing an news app.

I download a number of news items (an item has title, content, images, etc) from a feed. Then I will store all items into a `CoreData db`.

At the same time, I may fetch items from the db and show them on the UI.

I understand that the CoreData db operations (especially if heavy) may affect and lag the UI, so I want to put all CoreData operations into `NSOpeartionQueue` with lowest thread priority. For example, a typical operation might be fetching all items of a feed and make them ready for the UI.

Since CoreData is not thread safe and contexts inside an operation and main thread are different, **here comes the question: how can I give these items  to the main thread so main thread can update the UI accordingly?**

---

### Proposal

I have two possible solutions.

*The first solution* is that **for each NSManagedObject items, I create a new item which is not related to any context** and then give all news items back to main thread. Then main thread uses these new items as using a non-NSManagedObject. This solution has a disadvantage: memory cost. I have to double the memory for all fetched items.

*The second solution* is that when fetching, in the NSOperation, I don't fetch anything other than the objectId of those items. And then **give all objectIds to the main thread and main thread can read all the real NSManagedObject items from its own context**. This solution also has a disadvantage: possible lag for the UI. Since reading db will really occur again in main thread, I am afraid that the reading will affect the UI.

---

**Anyone can give me some suggestions?**

Thanks

Comment: This might give you some really nice solutions: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Comment: @rckoenes this is a nice article. But it does not say anything about whether there is performance penalty on the UI if I let the main thread to fetch via `objectIds`